# MS Excel : Identify Cell containing 2 or more "@" / two or more email addresses

Tags: excel, email, excel-formula, ms-office, email-validation

What formula should I use to identify a cell containing two or more "**@**" ?

For example, I copied thousands of emails from a sheet and pasted it to a new sheet (emails are all in one column only) but there's a case that a cell may contain two or more emails [*eg. abcd@efg.comhijk@lmn.com*], what I want is to **highlight/identify** those cell containing such so that I can easily fix or remove it from the list.

Any response to this will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "Highlight/identify" your cells...  Highlight your cells and choose "Conditional formatting" -> "Highlight Cell Rules" -> "Text that contains"  In the "Format cells that contain text" field, enter *@*@* and choose your highlight color.

[image: Formatting popup]

[image: Results]

Answer (score 1):

You can count the "@" symbol in the cell with this formula and if it is more than 2 then it will indicate with a TRUE flag

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"@","")))=2,"TRUE","FALSE")
```

Please see the image below for the formula used in excel

[image: See the image below]

Or you can put this formula in conditional formatting to highlight the cells when TRUE()

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"@","")))=2,TRUE(),FALSE())
```

[image]